# undefined method `_sash' for true:TrueClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, merit-gem

I using gem '[merit](https://github.com/tute/merit#defining-rules)' to give points to users when they create a comment. I also want to remove the points for create (5) when I delete the comment. I(admin) can delete comments. When I click to delete, I get an error in the title and points are not removed.

```
score 5, :on => ['comments#create'], category: 'gold_points'

score -5, :on => ['comments#destroy'], to: :user, category: 'gold_points'
```

I also see this in log

```
[merit] NoMethodError on `NilClass#user` (called from Merit::TargetFinder#other_target)
```

Comment: seems odd but can you try `score (5*-1), :on => ['comments#destroy'], to: :user, category: 'gold_points'`? Or with a lambda block: `score lambda{ |comment| -5 }, on: 'comments#destroy',`

Comment: I've tried both, but I still get the same error. I updated post with log.

Answer (score 0):

It's because on `destroy`, the `comment` doesn't exist anymore to call `user` on it and grant reputation.

See related issue: https://github.com/tute/merit/issues/171#issuecomment-44185696.